# How to use transaction scope within async method in a repository

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller

My repository has this async method that updates two tables.  The tables are in different schema, thus two contexts. The contexts are class variables in this repository.  This method is called from a webapi which is called by a Angular client application.  I need to ensure both insertions succeed or both fail.  After trying to insert a duplicated record failed in either context, the server will always remember the record no matter a non-duplicated record is passed in.  The server will return failure until the hosting server is rebooted. Does anyone know how to handle this in transaction scope?

```js
public class RepositoryAsync: IRepositoryAsync {
  //CareMgmtTool schema context
  private CareMgmtToolContext cmtCtx = new CareMgmtToolContext();

  //App schema context
  private AppContext appCtx = new AppContext();

  //UserProfile schema
  private UserProfileContext userProfileCtx = new UserProfileContext();

  public async Task < int > PostUserFSR(int userId, int fsrId) {
    //poor man's transaction scope
    bool operation1Success, operation2Success = false;
    UserProfile_UserFacilityServiceRole vm1 = new UserProfile_UserFacilityServiceRole();
    vm1.UserId = userId;
    vm1.FacilityServiceRoleId = fsrId;
    UserProfile_UserFacilityServiceRole ufsr_UserProfileSchema = userProfileCtx
      .UserProfile_UserFacilityServiceRole.Add(vm1);
    operation1Success = true;

    App_SUserFacilityServiceRole vm2 = new App_SUserFacilityServiceRole();
    vm2.UserId = userId;
    vm2.FacilityServiceRoleId = fsrId;
    App_SUserFacilityServiceRole ufsr_appSchema = appCtx.App_SUserFacilityServiceRole.Add(vm2);
    operation2Success = true;

    if (operation1Success && operation2Success) {
      await userProfileCtx.SaveChangesAsync();
      await appCtx.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    return ufsr_UserProfileSchema.UserFacilityServiceRoleId; //record key
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the documentation in 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx where it gives 3 scenarios using Transactions.  In my case I just used the 1st scenario that begin transaction in the same context.  Though the samples with all three scenarios use SQL command, I just use the EF LINQ add() and remove() without using SQL command nor TransactionScope.  Here is quote from the article "In summary, with the new Database.BeginTransaction() and Database.UseTransaction() API, the TransactiionScope approach is no longer necessary for most users."

Answer (score 0):

Please wrap the logic with transactionScope with TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption enabled. Here is good [source](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2014/12/16/participating-in-transactionscopes-and-asyncawait-going-deep-into-the-abyss/) as a reference. Please see the following code for an idea (note that this code hasn't been tested).

```
 public async Task < int > PostUserFSR(int userId, int fsrId) 
    {
        using (var scope = 
            new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
        {
            try{
            UserProfile_UserFacilityServiceRole vm1 = new UserProfile_UserFacilityServiceRole();
            vm1.UserId = userId;
            vm1.FacilityServiceRoleId = fsrId;
            UserProfile_UserFacilityServiceRole ufsr_UserProfileSchema = userProfileCtx
              .UserProfile_UserFacilityServiceRole.Add(vm1);
        
            App_SUserFacilityServiceRole vm2 = new App_SUserFacilityServiceRole();
            vm2.UserId = userId;
            vm2.FacilityServiceRoleId = fsrId;
            App_SUserFacilityServiceRole ufsr_appSchema = appCtx.App_SUserFacilityServiceRole.Add(vm2);
              await userProfileCtx.SaveChangesAsync();
              await appCtx.SaveChangesAsync();
        scope.Complete();
            return ufsr_UserProfileSchema.UserFacilityServiceRoleId; //record key
              }
        }
        catche(Exception ex)
        {
            return 0;
         }
    }
```